# Icon Popover (Angular 4+)

Tags: html, css, angular, popover

I am trying to make a popover, but for icon. The current implementation is with button.

Also, I am trying to make it popover to the right, not the bottom.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mde-popover)

Here is the icon:

```
<i (click)="infoButton()" class="icon-info"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with this library.

But you can try to add:

```
[mdePopoverOffsetX]="100" [mdePopoverArrowOffsetX]="0"
```

But I don't know if there is a good solution with this library

If you are using *Angular Material*, Check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rllqemrkxope?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-types-example.ts) to transform your button in icon with `mat-icon-button`

Comment: how can I make it an icon, not button?

Comment: I have edted my answer for you